# Maintain shared stack 'center' axis for layered plots

Tags: visualization, altair, vega-lite

I'm trying to create a faceted violin plot that has a shared interval selection between the facets. While I was able to get the interaction shared across the facets, I'm seeing weird behavior with each layer having it's own center axis for the stack. Causing the filtered section to not align with the unfiltered background distribution.

[image: Gif of altair issues]

**Is there a way to maintain axis consistency across layers?**

I tried differing stack alignments (center, left, right, etc); however, that doesn't seem to solve the issue as that will change it to a different type of chart rather than the centered violin plot.

I also tried elevating the encoding to a shared level. This didn't seem to fix the issue either.

[Vega editor example](https://vega.github.io/editor/#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)

[Colab example](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/13gYrhCZQzfBDffF7E7Bz0X7q-kdtwtgD?usp=sharing)